# NSMutableArray addsubview UIImageView when is in Event

Tags: ios, events, uiimageview

My images do not appear in my UIImageView when i am in event, in my viewDidLoad no problem.

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

```
if ( event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
{
    int i;
    int r;

    for ( i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; )
    {
        r =  (arc4random()%NbrCells) + 1;

        if (GridCell[r].hidden == NO)
        {
            // View position.

            CGFloat OriginX = GridCell[r].frame.origin.x;
            CGFloat OriginY = GridCell[r].frame.origin.y;
            CGFloat Height = GridCell[r].frame.size.height;
            CGFloat Whidth = GridCell[r].frame.size.width;

            [GridCell[r] removeFromSuperview];

            GridCell[r] = nil;

            GridCell[r] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

            GridCell[r].frame = CGRectMake(OriginX, OriginY, Whidth, Height);
            GridCell[r].hidden = NO;

            [self.MyImage1 addSubview:GridCell[r]];

            // [MyArray[r] addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NO]];

            i++;

            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Event stop, number delete = %d", i - 1);

}

if ( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)] )
    [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];
```

return;
}

Many Thanks.

Alan10977.

Comment: What is the exact problem? Do you get to your code? Is self.MyImage1 nil here? Which thread is it running in?

Comment: And never, ever, do `sleep()` in the UI thread!

Comment: I'd add to @Krumelur and say never, ever do `sleep(3)` anywhere!